# I would like to write a loop to generate the number of individuals in the same pack from the birthday, daily, all the way upto one year

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr, match

I have the following data. One dataframe that provides a list of birthdays of individuals and another that keeps a track of the individuals as well as others that are present. What I would essentially like to do is to write a loop that goes one by one on each individual of the first df and returns the total number of individuals in the same birth pack on the same day. I have provided a dummy data below.

```
df1
  date indiv pack
1  100     a    1
2  100     b    1
3  100     c    1
4  101     d    1

df2
  date indiv pack
1  100     a    1
2  100     b    1
3  100     c    1
4  101     d    1
5  101     e    1
6  101     f    2
7  101     g    2
8  102     h    3

output
  date indiv pack count
1  100     a    1     3
2  100     b    1     3
3  100     c    1     3
4  101     d    1     2
```

What I need the loop to do is see the following. Individual (a) born on day 100 matches with individual and day 100 in df2. Having matched, lets now get the total number of members in the same pack on day 100 and return this value to df1 in a new column (i.e. 3). Next, lets see individual (b). In df2 lets see where it matches, and we find there are 3 from the same pack, so lets add 3 in df1 row 2. Move further down, after a few iterations of the loop, and we see that individual (d) has only 2 other members from the same pack born on the same day, so the value returned would be 2...and so on.

I am getting stuck trying to write a for loop that goes one by one on df1 and getting the count. Ideally I would like to do this for 365 consecutive days to get a mean count of pack size from birthday+365 days (i.e. day 100, pack 1 had 3...day 101 pack 1 had 2...day 103 pack 1 had 0....get the mean and return to df1) and then move onto the next individual. After getting the mean of 365 days, I move onto the next individual in df1 and go over the same loop for 365 days from its birthday. Hope this is clear and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
~date, ~indiv, ~pack,
100,     "a",    1,
100,     "b",    1,
100,     "c",    1,
101,     "d",    1)


df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date, ~indiv, ~pack,
100,     "a",    1,
100,     "b",    1,
100,     "c",    1,
101,     "d",    1,
101,     "e",    1,
101,     "f",    2,
101,     "g",    2,
102,     "h",    3)

df1$count <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  pk <- df2 %>% 
    filter(indiv == df1$indiv[i] & date == df1$date[i]) %>%
    select(pack) %>%
    pull()
  df1$count[i] <- df2 %>% filter(pack == pk & date == df1$date[i]) %>% nrow()  
}
df1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>    date indiv  pack count
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1   100 a         1     3
#> 2   100 b         1     3
#> 3   100 c         1     3
#> 4   101 d         1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You could also do it like this without a loop:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
~date, ~indiv, ~pack,
100,     "a",    1,
100,     "b",    1,
100,     "c",    1,
101,     "d",    1)


df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date, ~indiv, ~pack,
100,     "a",    1,
100,     "b",    1,
100,     "c",    1,
101,     "d",    1,
101,     "e",    1,
101,     "f",    2,
101,     "g",    2,
102,     "h",    3)


df2 %>% 
  group_by(date, pack) %>% 
  summarise(indiv = data.frame(indiv = indiv), 
            date = first(date), 
            pack = first(pack),
            count = n()) %>% 
  unnest(indiv) %>% 
  right_join(df1)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'date', 'pack'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> Joining, by = c("date", "pack", "indiv")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   date, pack [2]
#>    date  pack indiv count
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <int>
#> 1   100     1 a         3
#> 2   100     1 b         3
#> 3   100     1 c         3
#> 4   101     1 d         2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much DaveArmstrong. I shall give this a try and see if it works for me. Any suggestions for doing this for the entire first year after an individual is born?

Comment: What do you mean by "entire first year"?  What does that imply for the dates we are considering?

Comment: So the dates are in a numeric format and not date format (days elapsed since 01/01/1900). So hypothetically if individual x is born on day 30000, I need to get the total number of individuals in the same pack on day 30000, 30001, 30002, ... , 30365 and get a mean. There will be new members that join a group and old ones that leave. Which is why I am interested in getting the mean. Therefore, I thought of saving the tally in a separate thing (like count) which would contain 365 values for each iteration and put the mean instead of the current count which currently gives that days information.

Comment: Dear DaveArmstrong, hope my previous comment was clear. If there is anything you would like me to clarify, I would be happy to.